# Pullback of an empty family

Tags: logic, category-theory

As I understand it, in the category of sets, there is no morphism $\{1\}\rightarrow\emptyset$. On the other hand, is one permitted to say sentences like the following?

"Consider the empty family $(\phi_\alpha)_\alpha$ of morphisms, where $\phi_\alpha:\{1\}\rightarrow\emptyset$."

For example, can one say,

"Find the pullback of the empty family $(\phi_\alpha)_\alpha$ of morphisms, where $\phi_\alpha:\{1\}\rightarrow\emptyset$."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. There's still a perfectly well-defined universal property (it's just vacuous) and a perfectly well-defined universal object satisfying it (exercise).